# Is there a way to disallow spaces in the user name registration form in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, forms, users

I hate spaces in usernames, a user can easily add two or more spaces without realizing it. I need to have more control over the username format than Drupal allows by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently wrote a custom module to disallow spaces and other characters in usernames. Feel free to comment on the code. I also modified [username_check](http://drupal.org/project/username_check) to do the same validations in the ajax callback.

```
//implement hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
function custom_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  //define validation function
  $form['#validate'][] = 'my_user_register_validate';
  //overwrite the username help text
  $form['account']['name']['#description'] = 'Username has to be between 5-15 characters long and can only contain letters and numbers';
}

function my_user_register_validate($form, &$form_state) {

  $output['error'] = FALSE;
  $username = $form_state['input']['name'];
  $password = $form_state['input']['pass']['pass1'];

  if (strlen($username) < 5 || strlen($username) > 15) {
    $output['error'] = TRUE;
    $output['msg'] = t('The username has to be between 5 and 15 characters long. ');
  }
  if (strpos($username,' ') > 0 || strpos($username,'.') > 0 || strpos($username,'-') > 0 || strpos($username,'_') > 0 || strpos($username, "'") !== FALSE ){
    $output['error'] = TRUE;
    $output['msg'] = t('Username cannot contain spaces . - _ ' . chr(39)  );
  }

//display username errors
  if ($output['error']){
    //drupal_set_message( $output['msg'], 'error');
    form_set_error('name', $output['msg']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this on Drupal 6 or 7? it doesn't seam to work on D7. I replaced the "custom_" part with "mymodulename_"

Comment: D7. You might have to clear your caches.

Comment: Thank's, every once in a while I forget to do the simple things in Drupal.

Comment: no problem, I do the same ;-)

Comment: Great this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

[User restrictions](http://drupal.org/project/user_restrictions) contrib module is a replacement for the 'access rules' functionality which was removed from Drupal 7.

You can make an access rule to prevent this with username creation.

Go to **administer » access control, tabs account rules » add rules** (admin/access/rules/add) and add the rules

```
% %
% %
```

(The last line has an ASCII 255 character)

Similar rules for dashes are also possible.

This is based on conversation at [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/56487)

Comment: In Drupal 7 "admin/access/rules/add" takes me to the administration page the functionality you speak of seams to be missing from D7. Is that a module that I have to install?

Comment: I updated my answer above. You need a contrib module in D7 to do this.

Comment: Since I am the developer of the User restrictions module (and became the maintainer only recently), I will add a note. I am rewriting the code, and the last available version still have some bugs. I will create a new official release between 7 days. Until then, don't install the module on a production site; before to use it for production, test it in a test site.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, thank you, I am looking forward for the official release.

Comment: The link is now: admin/config/people/user-restrictions/add to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use a username validation in Drupal7 is easy to remove some type of characters and white spaces and you can add your own type of validation also ,
    please check below function.

```
function my_module_my_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {

//birth year
  $year_of_birth = $form_state['values']['year_of_birth'];
  if ($year_of_birth && ($year_of_birth < 1900 || $year_of_birth > 2000)) {
    form_set_error('year_of_birth', 'Enter a year between 1900 and 2000.');
  }

//username
  $username = $form_state['values']['uname'];   
  if (strpos($username,' ') > 0 || strpos($username,'.') > 0 || strpos($username,'-') > 0 || strpos($username,'_') > 0 || strpos($username, "'") !== FALSE ){
    form_set_error('uname','User name cannot contain spaces . - _ ' . chr(39)  );
  }  
}
```

Comment: What is implied by the name `my_module_my_form_validate` ?  I think the question was  specifically about adding validation to user information entered during registration.  So .... shouldn't there not be a specific module name in there somewhere?  This answer seems simple and clear, but there's not enough information here to make it useful.